# Confused regarding @3x artwork for iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6-plus

I have an app in the App store to which I want to add @3x files. I read various posts but I am not sure how to proceed.

I read that coordinate space for the iPhone 6 plus is 414x736 points, (X3) that yields 1242x2208 pixels and not 1080x1920. Also I read that the iPhone 6+ will divide that by 1.15 before rendering to the display which will make it fit.

So lets say my App has a button image that is 44x44 pixels (the @2x file), then I should draw it as 44/2*3*1.15 to make it fit my 1242x2208 photoshop canvas. (/2 for points, times 3 for pixels *1.15 to overscale)

Now Apple documentation says @3x button need to have 66 pixels area, so that seems too small as it is not scaled up by 1.15.

This leads me to think my App canvas should be 1080x1920 which would avoid the iPhone having expensive rescale. So which is right?  of course @3x would not be @3x.

Comment: Forget the 1080x1920. The screen is 414x736 points or 1242x2208 pixels. That's all that matters.

Comment: You should go with 66, iOS will rescale for screen size automatically.

Comment: You just use the `@2X` assets with factor of 3/2 OR 1.5 (as example 44*1.5=66) and save with `@3X`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget the 1.15 thing or actual screen resolution. Just scale up your '@2x' assets by a factor of 3/2, and name them '@3x'. The rest will be taken care of by iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Check these links - how @3x image is works with 1080x1920 size..

http://aten.co/2014/09/12/designing-from-iphone-5-to-iphone-6-iphone-6-more-than-i-bargained-for/

You have to set images in image asset, so iOS automatically assign 2x & 3x images.. for different devices.